# acts_as_commentable_with_threading in Rails 4 won't save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've been working with the acts_as_commentable_with_threading gem and I can't get the comments to save.

My controller:

```
 class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @comment_hash = params[:comment]
    @obj = @comment_hash[:commentable_type].constantize.find(@comment_hash[:commentable_id])
    # Not implemented: check to see whether the user has permission to create a comment on this object
    @comment = Comment.build_from(@obj, current_user, @comment_hash[:body])

    if @comment.save
      flash[:notice] = "New comment saved!!!!!"
      redirect_to status_path(@obj)
      #redirect_to profiles_path(current_user)
    else
      flash[:alert] = "didn't save"
      redirect_to status_path(@obj)
    end
  end

private
# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def comment_params
  params.require(:comment,:commentable_id,:commentable_type, :user_id, :body)
end
end
```

When I check the development log I can see that the values in the hash are all populated and I can see the transaction start the save, but it is immediately rolled back.

```
Started POST "/comments" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-30 10:47:54 +0100
Processing by CommentsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",       "authenticity_token"=>"ojRIz0hj0m8BL613Q9W4DHkYNZqO8eeMvR2gEM6Qhp8=", "comment"=>   {"body"=>"test comment", "commentable_id"=>"52", "commentable_type"=>"Status"}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
[1m[35mStatus Load (0.1ms)[0m  SELECT "statuses".* FROM "statuses" WHERE "statuses"."id" = ? ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["id", "52"]]
[1m[36mUser Load (0.3ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 6 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1[0m
[1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  begin transaction
[1m[36m (0.1ms)[0m  [1mrollback transaction[0m
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/statuses/52
Completed 302 Found in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)
```